Where does the squeaking sound come from?
Seems like there is a squeaking sound from the front wheel, around the caliper perhaps?
I added a video, please try to ignore the rear hub sound - you can clearly hear the squeaking.
What I was trying to do is to clean the caliper and disk area with cleaning agent for brakes, and I believe it helped, but then after 1 ride, the noise always comes back.
link to video
Would appreciate any help, thanks!
